# Cuda Toolkit 6.0 unsupported compiler Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cuda, installation

I am trying to install Cuda 6.0 in my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, but it keeps throwing my the following error:

```
Error: unsupported compiler: 4.8.2. Use --override to override this check.
```

Which gcc version should I have for this?

Answer (score 6):

use this command to install Cuda:

```
sudo ./cuda_6.0.37_linux_64.run -toolkit -samples -silent -override
```

Comment: if you do not specify '-driver ' will the driver be installed?

Answer (score 6):

try the following command ./cuda_6.5.14_linux_32.run --override

Answer (score 3):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#system-requirements)

Ubuntu 14.04 is not a supported distribution for CUDA 6.0, niether is gcc 4.8.2

> Which gcc version should I have for this?

You should have gcc version 4.8.1 (or older) for CUDA 6.

I recommend installing [CUDA 6.5RC](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) instead (available for download to registered developers), for which Ubuntu 14.04 is a supported distro, along with its default version of gcc.